# Multiple IE background linear-gradient css

Tags: css, background, linear-gradients

I am trying to achieve the following design with `background: linear-gradient` I am able to get the left side but unable to get a dual linear-gradient rule to work in order to style bottom sides

`background: linear-gradient(4deg, #000 5%, transparent 5%), linear-gradient(-4deg, #000 5%, transparent 5%);` this is being applied to a simple `div`.

The reason for using this CSS rule is because IE does not support **clip-path** and **polygon**

[image]

Comment: Also, the color stops in % depend on the width and height of the div, so unless you know exactly how high and how wide it will be in pixels, you will never get the exact shape right.

Comment: Solution: throw away this idea and use a pseudo element with a border.

Comment: @MrLister hmm pseduo element with a border... not sure how to do this method. what should I be looking for in my search or an example?

Comment: Arrow border, or triangular border. Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rqahpuzg/).